# How to create a Win 8 User using an existing user profile

Tags: windows-8.1, user-profiles

I've installed a new SSD and am re-paving my system with Windows 8.1.  My Windows 7 system was run with the \Users directory redirected to my second drive (which I assigned the drive letter U: to). So I have a U:\Users\dave directory containing all my Windows 7 profile, documents, etc.

Installing Windows 8.1 was something of a trial and error process. The first time I  installed it, using my Microsoft Account (Dave Hanna), it created the user, and mapped it's profile to the U:\Users\dave directory, which was just what I wanted.  And I was able to move around in it, access my files, etc.

But some things weren't exactly right, and I ended up re-installing. Every time since then (several tries), it ends up creating a new directory in U:\Users with a different name (e.g. U:\Users\dave.dave-laptop).

Is there away that I can get it to create the user and assign it's profile to the existing user directory the way it did the first time?